# iOS Localization how to add an existed folder with localization files

Tags: ios, localization, special-folders

How to add an existed folder with localization files.
I have an existed project with english as base, then have en.lproj.

And I have other localization files in file system names with ja.lproj.
However, If i directly import folder ja.lproj to xcode, seems not work, in project tab, it shows 0 files localized, and while start app, it will crash.

I know it may work, I choose one english version file, add plus in file inspector, then will add another lang version, however, it's not convenient, and new file will locate in en.lproj sub-folder, it's strange.

anybody can help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to do that with folders. Although you can do that with files. Just define different versions of the same file for different languages. Like this:

[image]